# How to mount 2 external storage directors to Android emulator 4.2?

Tags: android, emulation

I create 1 android emulator 4.2 with an external storage is a virtual sd card
Now i want mount 1 more external storage to my emulator so it has 2 external storage directories
So could i do that? Anyone has experience about this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Android does not have support for more than one external storage directory at this time. Therefore, the Android emulator does not have support for more than one external storage directory at this time.

Comment: Thanks for comment but do you have any reference about this? I just want to confirm it.